# has_many through build

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, associations, has-many-through

I have two models. User and Account as follows

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :manages
  has_many :users, :through => :manages
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :manages
  has_many :accounts, :through => :manages
end
```

If I were to use the rails console and create an instance of account by

```
acc = usr.accounts.build
acc.save
```

The following command would return the account instance created

```
usr.accounts
```

But the following command would not return the user instance

```
acc.users
```

Also when I look at the Join table, there is no entry created. What am missing here? I thought by using the build method that it automatically creates the join model entry.

Comment: Are there any validation errors on the account object?

Comment: @Stephen
nop. When I do
`acc.save`
no errors appear on the console

Answer (score 2):

Try saving the user object instead.

```
acc = usr.accounts.build
usr.save
```

Comment: Nope, the idea is that saving the parent saves unpersisted associated children. See https://www.evernote.com/l/AAL0VZ4pfXFJtJEnMeSo2vL4XWn-tLDD7E0 where I show a parent (User) child (Feedbacks) relationship demonstrating it in a rails console.

Comment: Oops, sorry, after re-reading your link to that particular rails issue, I may have misinterpreted the question as my example was not for a has_many :through relationship. I didn't check that case. And I won't have time to look into this further any time soon. Great question, @neanderslob!

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a full error report if you use **.save!** rather than **.save**

Using a **has_many :through** please try adding a model

```
class Manage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account
end
```