# Using build does not create join model on has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

My 2 models:

```
Class TeamHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_to_team_histories
  has_many :players, through: :player_to_team_histories

  belongs_to :team
end

Class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :player_to_team_histories
  has_many :team_histories, through: :player_to_team_histories
end
```

I can't get the `player_to_team_histories` to be created using `@team_history.players.build`, but it works fine with `@team_history.players.create`

```
>>team = Team.create
>>team_history = team.team_histories.create
>>player = team_history.players.create
>>player.team_histories.count
1
>>player2 = team_history.players.build
>>player2.team_histories.count
0
>>player2.save
>>player2.team_histories.count
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging on this because I didn't immediately know the answer. I found that `#build` does setup the association models but only from the parent model down to the children. This means that in your example from above, rails is behaving as designed.

```
>>team = Team.create
>>team_history = team.team_histories.create
>>player = team_history.players.create
>>player.team_histories.count
1
>>player2 = team_history.players.build
>>player2.team_histories.count
0
```

This is totally as expected. If you called:

```
>>team_histories.players
```

your new player would be in the list. So if instead of:

```
>>player2.save
```

you ran:

```
>>team_histories.save
```

your new player would be saved.

Jonathan Wallace's answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036870/has-many-through-build?rq=1) says basically the same thing.

Comment: Copy paste error.  Thanks for the catch.  I just copied from my model incorrectly.  Same problem persists.